# Pass checkbox value IF the checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, checkbox, meteor-helper

I have a list of checkboxes that looks like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="west" name="west" id="west" checked="{{isChecked}}">West</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox"  checked="{{isChecked}}" name="airport" id="airport" value="airport">Airport</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox"  checked="{{isChecked}}" name="north" id="north" value="north">North</label>
</div>
```

I have managed to pass the status of each checkbox as a boolean to the collection like this:

```
var eventLocation = [
event.target.west.checked,
event.target.airport.checked,
]
```

However, I would like to pass only the value of the checked checkboxes. I know I can pass the value of the checkboxes with `event.target.west.value`, but to get only the checked ones I would have to write many conditionals, which would not scale well. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quickly gather all checked checkboxes with:

```
var checked = $("input:checked");
```

This will return an array that you can loop over to get the id, value, or name.

```
checked.forEach(function(c){
  console.log('input id: '+c.id+' name: '+c.name+' value: '+c.val+' is checked!');
});
```

Comment: Fantastic - thank you so much! I actually implemented something quite similar:    

`$('.event-location-form input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
       if(this.checked){
        eventLocation.push($(this).val());
       }
  });`

Comment: You can do this without the `if (this.checked)`! `$('.event-location-form input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () { eventLocation.push($(this).val()); });`